swagger-codegen-maven-plugin, how to generate Spring's controller @RequestParam annotation without providing value
I'm using the Swagger plugin to generate controllers in Spring, and here's where the problem with dynamic parameters arises. If I set something like this in the YAML file:
- name: searchParams
  in: query
  schema:
    additionalProperties:
      type: string

Then the plugin generates this in the controller.
@RequestParam(value="searchParams", required = false) Map<String, String> searchParams
The problem here is that I want to have dynamic parameters - normally in Spring, you do this by using the @RequestParam annotation without the value attribute - then all request attributes go into this map, but the plugin always adds this parameter, which kills the idea of dynamic queries. Does anyone know how to do this?
